# How to handle shared memory in a multi threaded environment?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, ipc, shared-memory

I have a client-server model. A multithreaded client sends a message to the server over the TCP sockets. The server is also multiple threaded with each request handled by a thread from the worker pool.

Now, the server must send back the message to the client via shared-memory IPC. For example:

```
multi threaded client --- GET /a.png --> server
                                          |
                                          |
                                       one worker
                                          |
                                          |
                                         \ /
                       puts the file descriptor into the shared memory
```

When worker thread adds the information into the shared memory, how do I make sure that it is read by the same client that requested it?

I feel clueless here as to how to proceed. Currently, I have created one segment of shared memory and there are 20 threads on the server and 10 threads on the client.

Comment: Since threads share all their memory already, why are you trying to use IPC? What's the point in putting a file descriptor in shared memory since a file descriptor is only meaningful inside a process and shared memory is for inter-process sharing?

Comment: Obviously there needs to be some way to decide where to put the response in the shared memory, and then tell the client where the response is.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use shared memory at all?  You might be better off just using message-passing.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I could have communicated back and forth using just sockets but need to have shared memory when replying back

Comment: What happens if you don't have shared memory when replying back?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Sorry I did not get you. You mean running out of space?

Comment: @Amanda you said you need to have shared memory but you didn't say why you need it.  So I was curious as to what would happen if you didn't use it -- why would that approach not work?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I could have the communication both ways with the web sockets, but the environment I am working with insists on sending back the reply using the shared memory. Although it does not insist on web sockets.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I want the two processes to be communicating via shared memory. Now both the two processes are multi-threaded. How would you attempt this?

Comment: I wouldn’t, because getting it to work reliably would be more trouble than it’s worth.  If you want to do it, you’ll need to use some kind of multi-process mutex to serialism access to some kind of data structure in the shared memory region that tracks which portions of the shared memory are being used for what purpose.  You’ll also need a way for thread A to notify thread B when a portion of the shared memory has been updated and is ready for thread B to look at (sockets or IPC would do)

Comment: You can't put file descriptors in shared memory, like @DavidSchwartz said. Well, you can put the file descriptor's *number* there, but that's useless, because when you read(23, ...) in the second process it will just say "no such file descriptor" because that process doesn't have a file descriptor number 23.

Answer (score -1):

While you can use IPC between threads, it's generally not a good idea. Threads share all memory anyway since they are part of the same process and there are very efficient mechanisms for communications between threads.

It might just be easier to have the same thread handle a request all the way through. That way, you don't have to hand off a request from thread to thread. However, if you have a pool of requests that are being worked on, it often makes sense to have a thread be able to "put down" a request and then later be able to have that thread or a different thread "pick up" the request.

The easiest way to do this is to make all the information related to the request live in a single structure or object. Use standard thread synchronization tools (like mutexes) to control finding the object, taking ownership of it, and so on.

So when an I/O thread receives a request, it creates a new request object, acquires a mutex, and adds it to the global collection of requests the server is working on. Worker threads can check this global collection to see which requests need work or they can be explicitly dispatched by the thread that created the request.

Comment: I did not understand. If a client thread `T` makes a request to another multi-threaded process. How can thread `T` be sure that the message received from shared memory is corresponding to what it asked for?

Comment: The client thread that has sent the message via sockets must wait for the message to arrive in the shared memory before it can do something with that data. But somehow the thread must know before reading the message that, it is indeed reading the correct message.

Comment: I downvoted this because the client and server are not threads in the same process.

Comment: @user253751 That doesn't change anything. The client and server communicate over TCP.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You are saying that code which runs in one process should just run in a different process instead. I assume there is a reason why the code is divided into more than one process.

Comment: @user253751 You have completely misunderstood the question. Look at this part, "puts the file descriptor into the shared memory". A file descriptor is only meaningful in a single process. He is talking about coordinating worker threads with I/O threads. His client and server communicate using TCP.